# Displaying Multiple Reasons for Putting Question on Hold

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Question [83919](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/83919/finding-the-numerical-solution-to-a-polynomial-of-a-high-degree) was put on-hold today with the reason

> put on hold as off-topic by Daniel Lichtblau, bbgodfrey, Silvia, gpap,
>   m_goldberg 2 hours ago
>
> This question appears to be off-topic. The users who voted to close
>   gave this specific reason:  •"This question cannot be answered without
>   additional information. Questions on problems in code must describe
>   the specific problem and include valid code to reproduce it. Any data
>   used for programming examples should be embedded in the question or
>   code to generate the (fake) data must be included." – Daniel
>   Lichtblau, Silvia, gpap

In fact, I did not vote to close the question for that reason, and I would prefer that all the reasons given for closure be displayed.  Doing so would be both more accurate and more informative.

In this case, I voted to close the question, because it largely duplicated a question asked by the OP several days earlier.

Comment: Apparently, in this new scheme, the displayed reason is chosen by majority vote. I understand that it can look cluttered if all the reasons chosen by all the voters are displayed; maybe an option to toggle the display of other reasons chosen?

Comment: I was annoyed by this quite some times. I especially hate it when this happens on occasions when you vehemently disagree with the other close reasons and you end up bundled all together.

Comment: Related on MSE: [Distinguish close votes by reason](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54917/distinguish-close-votes-by-reason?rq=1). Note the vast amount of rep thrown at that question over its ~5 years of life. This has been around for a long time and caused a fair a mount of friction (e.g. Tsuyoshi Ito's answer), but so far it looks very unlikely that the SE team will implement this, unfortunately.

Comment: @episanty  Thanks for the very informative link.  I now shall wait for my question to be closed, perhaps for five different reasons.

Comment: Why? What I would like is for one question like this on every site with double-digit score. By all means keep this open - hopefully the SE UX team will eventually come up with something clever if everyone keeps asking for this. All I was saying is - be aware that this problem has a history and is unlikely to be solved soon.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note that I was the final closer, but my name does not appear as signing off on the reason given. I, too, disagreed with the majority on the reason.

I strongly support any effort to get all reasons for closing on record. I think not doing so defrauds the whole community. I think everybody, but especially the OP, has the right to know all the reasons for which a question was closed.